# Is there a way in Gradle to define what patterns of artifacts should, (or should not), be resolved via a repository?

Tags: gradle, artifactory, nexus

Is there a way in Gradle to explicitly define where certain artifacts should be coming from?

We have a legacy project which is being on-boarded to use a proper artifact repository manager, instead of a network share. However, we have multiple repositories from which artifacts are being downloaded. We'd like to be able to fine-grain where certain artifacts should be coming from, until we can fully on-board to the artifact repository manager in question.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible as of Gradle 5.1

https://docs.gradle.org/5.1/release-notes.html#repository-to-dependency-matching

> **Repository to dependency matching**
>
> It is now possible to match repositories to dependencies, so that Gradle doesn't search for a dependency in a repository if it's never going to be found there.

See the docs for more details: https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec::matching_repositories_to_dependencies

Comment: Right... Great! We're using 4.2.x. Is there a workaround for this in such an older version, or is the only way to upgrade?

Comment: Probably not without some work/hacks. You can try to customizing/hacking [dependency resolution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html), but really at that point it would be easier (if you're able to) to simply upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!